# templates vs inheritance for method exposing one-to-many relationship

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

In the context of a game engine of sorts, consider the following component-based design:

1. A Node class that can have many Behaviors.
2. A user of the API can create Node instances and add as many Behavior
   subclasses as they want; thru Behavior subclasses they essentially
   customize the game logic. They cannot, however, create new
   subclasses of Node. They can also ask a Node for any behaviors it
   might have.
3. Given the above, Node will have 2 methods:

   `addBehavior`: adds a concrete Behavior type to Node.

   `getBehaviors`: returns all Behaviors from Node of a
   specified type, including just Behavior, meaning 'all behavior types' , optionally filtering by some predicate.

My dilema is whether to implement the above using templates vs regular inheritance, since I find drawbacks in both approaches; I'm not super happy with either approach I've come up with so far and I am wondering if there is any clear reason why I would go with one implementation over the other.

Consider the following starting point:

```
class Behavior {
public:
    virtual void doYourThing() = 0;
};

class Jump : public Behavior {
public:
    virtual void doYourThing() {
        //  Jump!
    }
};

class Run : public Behavior {
public:
    virtual void doYourThing() {
        //  Run at runSpeed!
    }

    int runSpeed;
};

class Node {
    //  addBehavior:
    //  getBehaviors:
private:
    unordered_map<type_index, vector<Behavior*>> behaviorsM;
};
```

Now comes the part of implementing `addBehavior` and `getBehavior`

**The inheritance approach:**

```
void addBehavior(Behavior& behavior) {
    behaviorsM[typeid(behavior)].push_back(&behavior);
}

template<class ElementType>
using Predicate = function<bool(ElementType& e, bool& stop)>;

const vector<Behavior*> getBehaviors(ClassType type = typeid(Behavior), Predicate<Behavior> predicate = nullptr) {
    vector<Behavior*> unfilteredBehaviors;
    if (type == typeid(Behavior)) {
        for (auto pair : behaviorsM) {
            vector<Behavior*>& behaviors = behaviorsM[pair.first];
            unfilteredBehaviors.insert(end(unfilteredBehaviors), begin(behaviors), end(behaviors));
        }
    }
    else {
        unfilteredBehaviors = behaviorsM[type];
    }

    if (!predicate) {
        predicate = [](const Behavior& b, bool& stop){return true;};
    }

    bool stop = false;
    vector<Behavior*> results;
    for (auto behavior : unfilteredBehaviors) {
        if(predicate(*behavior, stop)) {
            results.push_back(behavior);
            if (stop) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

So far so good. But consider if I had added a few behaviors to a `Node`, and later on I want to set the runSpeed of any `Run` behaviors it might have (and I no longer have my own refs to the behaviors; otherwise I'd just set them thru those typed refs). The situation would be something like this:

```
Jump j1;
Run r1;
Run r2;

node.addBehavior(j1);
node.addBehavior(r1);
node.addBehavior(r2);

//  Later on... no longer have the refs j1,r1,r2, so I need to query the node:
for (Behavior* behavior : node.getBehaviors(typeid(Run))) {
    static_cast<Run*>(behavior)->runSpeed = 20;
}
```

The good:

- Write once, can use with any Behavior.
- Can be put in the implementation file, leaving only the declaration
  in the interface file for Node.

The bad:

- The user of this thing will have to cast to Behavior subtypes if they
  need to do anything particular to that subtype, even when they are
  guaranteed that they are getting all behaviors of that specific
  subtype; same if they want to use the predicate function.

So...

**The "generic" approach:**

```
template <class BehaviorType,
typename enable_if<
is_base_of<Behavior, BehaviorType>::value &&
!is_abstract<BehaviorType>::value,
BehaviorType>::type* = nullptr>
void addBehavior(BehaviorType& behavior) {
    behaviorsM[typeid(BehaviorType)].push_back(&behavior);
}

template<class ElementType>
using Predicate = function<bool(ElementType& e, bool& stop)>;

template <class BehaviorType,
typename enable_if<
is_base_of<Behavior, BehaviorType>::value,
BehaviorType>::type* = nullptr>
const vector<BehaviorType*> getBehaviors(Predicate<BehaviorType> predicate = nullptr) {
    vector<Behavior*> unfilteredBehaviors;
    type_index requestedType = typeid(BehaviorType);
    if (requestedType == typeid(Behavior)) {
        for (auto pair : behaviorsM) {
            vector<Behavior*>& behaviors = behaviorsM[pair.first];
            unfilteredBehaviors.insert(end(unfilteredBehaviors), begin(behaviors), end(behaviors));
        }
    }
    else {
        unfilteredBehaviors = behaviorsM[requestedType];
    }

    if (!predicate) {
        predicate = [](const BehaviorType& b, bool& stop){return true;};
    }

    bool stop = false;
    vector<BehaviorType*> results;
    for (auto behavior : unfilteredBehaviors) {
        BehaviorType* concreteBehavior = static_cast<BehaviorType*>(behavior);
        if(predicate(*concreteBehavior, stop)) {
            results.push_back(concreteBehavior);
            if (stop) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Mmm.. well let's see. Now I can do this:

```
for (Run* behavior : node.getBehaviors<Run>()) {
    behavior->runSpeed = 20;
}
```

I can also, btw, do this, if I feel it's more descriptive:

```
node.addBehavior<Jump>(j1);
node.addBehavior<Run>(r1);
node.addBehavior<Run>(r2);
```

But this was not free in my opinion. The way I see it:

The good:

- The user gets a vector of behaviors already cast to the subtype requested, which seems coherent with the way one would think in abstract terms about 'get me all jump behaviors'. This is a BIG plus in my mind, in terms of user experience.
- Write once, use for any types... sort of.. see the bad.

The bad:

- Personally I like thinking of the header file as the public and protected API reference of a class. If I put the template definitions in the header file, I feel I've polluted what should have been a brief 'interface file' with all the implementation details.
- If I put the template definitions in the implementation file, I have to do explicit instantiation for each Behavior type, whether in the cpp or in a separate file that the cpp will include. Essentially defeating the purpose of 'write once, use for any type'. This is because the idea is that users of this thing will constantly create new Behaviors. Requiring them to also add create and get explicit instantiations to some file for each Behavior sucks. I guess I could add some code-gen script that adds them automatically, but still.. it all makes me a bit sad.
- In reality, the compiler is actually creating one version of each method for each type, which also makes me kind of sad to think about for the case of a templated method, as opposed to a whole templated class, in which it makes sense for the class template to be the 'blueprint' for creating class types.
- Finally, the user is spared from casting, but internally, the template implementation actually does cast every single instance of Behavior!

So the bottom line is that having the user do the casts feels bad and the template version provides a better user experience for clients of the class, but at the expense of a bunch of stuff. So I'm not sure if this is a valid use for templates and if it merits all the drawbacks.

Comment: Regarding the various behaviours, cannot you implement them as [policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)?

Comment: @vsoftco How would policies make it possible to access the elements returned by 'getBehaviors' as concrete subtypes without casting but at the same time avoiding all the template implementation's drawbacks?